# Road Lane Detection program failing to detect lane properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to develop a program that can detect lanes on the road. I have experimented with both Hough Line Transform and Probabilistic Hough Line Transform. However none of these are getting the results that I want.

Original Image:

[image]

Hough Line Transform

[image]
[image]

Probabilistic Hough Line Transform

[image]
[image]

It seems that for Hough Line Transform, I can at least detect the entire lane, but unfortunately, the line just goes on infinitely (until they move off the picture), to the point where the lines intersect with each other, which is not a good graphical lane detection marker.

I also tried Probalistic Hough Line Transform, and the green line used for lane detection does not go off to infinitely like the other one, but it fails to mark and detect the entire lane.

I am trying to replicate results here (by writing it in Python)

http://www.transistor.io/revisiting-lane-detection-using-opencv.html

What can I do to fix this problem?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import imutils

def invert_img(img):
    img = (255-img)
    return img

def canny(imgray):
    imgray = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5,5), 200)
    canny_low = 5
    canny_high = 150

    thresh = cv2.Canny(imgray,canny_low,canny_high)
    return thresh

def filtering(imgray):
    thresh = canny(imgray)

    minLineLength = 1
    maxLineGap = 1


    lines = cv2.HoughLines(thresh,1,np.pi/180,0)
    #lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh,2,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
    print lines.shape

    # Code for HoughLinesP
    '''
    for i in range(0,lines.shape[0]):
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[i]:
            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
    '''

    # Code for HoughLines

    for i in range(0,5):
        for rho,theta in lines[i]:
            a = np.cos(theta)
            b = np.sin(theta)
            x0 = a*rho
            y0 = b*rho
            x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
            y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
            x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
            y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)


    return thresh


img = cv2.imread('images/road_0.bmp')


imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = imutils.resize(img, height = 500)
imgray = imutils.resize(imgray, height = 500)

thresh = filtering(imgray)

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('result', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool topic! First of all, why did you add the Gaussian blur? Your source article doesn't mention that at all. If I remove that, I instantly get extra crazy lines, which I can tone down with the canny_low and canny_high. About the best I could find was low=100 and high=180.

[image: screenshot of algorithm finding road lines]

Second, you did quite a good job translating the article to Python. However, I think you left out a crucial detail. The author writes:

```
// Canny algorithm
Mat contours;
Canny(image,contours,50,350);
Mat contoursInv;
threshold(contours,contoursInv,128,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

You implement the Canny function (cv2.canny()), but you don't call the threshold function. According to [documentation I found](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold), this function "applies a fixed-level threshold to each array element." I experimented with your code and came up with the following.

```
#thresh = canny(imgray) # original
edges = canny(imgray) # docs refer to return value as "edges"

retval, dst = cv2.threshold(edges, 128, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Two values are returned - retval isn't particularly important for us right now. dst is the destination 2D array of image data after thresholding. You would then update your call to cv2.HoughLines and cv2.HoughLinesP replacing "thresh" with "dst." When I did this I got a lot more interesting behavior, though I was not able to find the correct tuning values to make the lines work well.

So, hopefully that gives you some pointers. Try my tips, and also read the article once or twice more to double check that you have the same program flow as the author. This seems like a fun project, have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I get strange results like this: http://s13.postimg.org/ok14ocw2v/image.jpg  I probably replicated your code incorrrectly, do you mind editing your comment to include the full code that you used? Thank you

Comment: Ah, I apologize. It probably wasn't clear from what I wrote.This image I posted is simply a result of the "First" step I described.

\\


When I implement the "Second" step, I also get the full image mostly filled up, similar to your image. I don't know why this is. However, I'm guessing it's on the right track because it's following the article for closely. I would guess it's a problem with tweaking those values (128, 255, canny_low, canny_high). Also there might be some additional code we haven't added from the original article, yet.

\\

I hope that helps!